# How to apply a class to selected item in navigation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I searched through various answers for the same issue but none of them fit my problem. I have a navigation that is partially hard-coded and database driven and I want to apply a class to the item that has been clicked. I tried this simple JS function but it is not working.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li onclick="funk(this)"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <?php
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM categories");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $cat_id=$row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title=$row['cat_title'];
    echo "<li onclick='funk(this)'><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

---

```
function funk(el) {
    var kids = document.getElementById("menu").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
       kids[i].className="c1";
    }
    el.className="c2";
}
```

---

```
.c2{background-color:#f65;}
.c1{background-color:#000;}
```

Anyone?

Comment: I see jquery in tags, but code?!

Comment: Your current code should do it. Are you clicking the `<a>` element and therefore refreshing the page?

Comment: most likely after the anchor is clicked, it redirect and resets it so it looks like nothings happened

Comment: is this php, js & css all in separate files / places? Because obviously this code would not work... Does `el` give you the right DOM object?

Comment: @six fingered man i am doing evaluation to see if $_GET['cat'] is set or not and therefore i display the content from database in a div element based on that

Comment: @Shan Robertson  js code and css are separate files included in index.php properliy with link and script tags in the head section.Php code is in index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could just use the `$_GET['cat']` to know where you are right now, and add a condition inside the while loop to mark your current position. Rough example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

    $active = (isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat'] == $cat_id) ? 'c2' : 'c1'; // class switches
    echo "<li class='$active'><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: This partially solved my problem.Items from database are being highlighted but the one hardcoded is not.Thanks anyway

Comment: @admir is the `home`? only be the one hardcoded? just add another condition in it: `<li <?php echo !isset($_GET['cat']) ? 'class="c2"' : 'class="c1"'; ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>`